# Ways to draw a line with float end-points in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am annotating images for ML segmentation. Some of the objects are small and the boundary could take a fraction of a pixel. I found the annotator (CVAT) that can mark borders with sub-pixel accuracy, giving polygon's coordinates as floats. However, when I try to make a mask in OpenCV, all of the drawing functions (lines, polygons, contours) only accept coordinates as integers.

I understand that line either colors a pixel of it doesn't and there could never be a half-colored pixel without changing resolution. But I think there could be some benefit to providing float end-points of a line. Below are the examples of why I am seeking this functionality at all.

[image: Line with int end-points]

[image: Line with float end-points]

As you can see, both lines round to the same end-point pixels. But the float one passes through different pixels, which could eventually mark object's boundary on a mask with better precision. Note, I am not sure that is exactly how OpenCV draws lines, it is solely for demonstration purposes.

When I am generating masks directly from the annotation software it actually provides leaner masks than those I produce in OpenCV. Which I suspect is due to them using "sub-pixel precision polygons".

So my questions are:

1. Am I missing something and OpenCV actually has this functionality.
2. If not, what would be the best way to emulate it? The only thing that comes to mind now is traversing a line and manually coloring each individual pixel in numpy, which sounds very slow.
3. Is there any other Python library that does have this functionality?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50322593/sub-pixel-accuracy-for-polygon-drawing-in-python

Comment: (1) opencv drawing functions, primarily the `line()` API, are fsck'd so don't expect sanity there. line thickness is completely bonkers, if you ask for LINE_AA style. (2) they all have a `shift` parameter. pass `4` there, and multiply all coordinates by 16 (2^4). that'll give you subpixel locations.